# r survey package - no confidence interval in svyby

Tags: r, survey

I have a survey data and I want to generate proportion with confidence interval with `svyby` function but I could not get the confidence interval and I only get the proportion.

```
library(haven)
library(survey)
Data_STEPs2016 \<- read_dta("Downloads/New Data/Data_STEPs2016.dta")
steps1395 \<- svydesign(id=Data_STEPs2016$code,weights = Data_STEPs2016$weight_Q,data = Data_STEPs2016)
svyby(\~t2,\~i07,design = steps1395, FUN = svyciprop, keep.var = FALSE)
```

The result I get is something like this:

```
svyby(\~t2,\~i07,design = steps1395, FUN = svyciprop, keep.var = FALSE)

i07  statistic
0    0 0.14332878
1    1 0.11922225
2    2 0.10394157
3    3 0.12091622
4    4 0.14260478
5    5 0.10390742
6    6 0.09138277
7    7 0.09750685
8    8 0.07722408
9    9 0.07022950
10  10 0.10392619
11  11 0.06465898
12  12 0.12214870
13  13 0.11607801
14  14 0.11861874
15  15 0.09637536
16  16 0.05414722
17  17 0.07987077
18  18 0.08505400
19  19 0.09966016
20  20 0.09301776
21  21 0.07819750
22  22 0.07396172
23  23 0.10893622
24  24 0.12906301
26  26 0.13013662
27  27 0.05522789
28  28 0.05326462
29  29 0.05739153
30  30 0.12571282
```

I did get answer with the following code :

```
svytable(\~t2+i07,steps1395)
prop.table(svytable(\~t2+i07,steps1395),margin = 1)
confint(prop.table(svytable(\~t2+i07,steps1395),margin = 1))
svyciprop(\~t2,steps1395,method = "likelihood",level = 0.95)`
```

But I need proportion by groups such as gender or location of living.
I also read the manual but in the `svyby` parts there is example of `svyciprop` as the function in the `svyby`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`svyby` has an option to show confidence intervals. For example, with one of the built-in example datasets

```
> svyby(~I(ell>50), ~stype, dclus1, svyciprop,vartype="ci")
  stype I(ell > 50)        ci_l      ci_u
E     E  0.11805556 0.066048776 0.2021490
H     H  0.07142857 0.005409131 0.5210736
M     M  0.04000000 0.003850809 0.3099199
```

To check: this is what you get for just the first subset by hand

```
> svyciprop(~I(ell>50), subset(dclus1,stype=="E"))
                   2.5% 97.5%
I(ell > 50) 0.118 0.066   0.2
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It helped me to solve my problem, but I have faced another problem. The result in our example in 97.5% intervals only has one digit.  Let's say I want to report it as a percentage I need more than one digit. Using the round function would only make the 0.188 round and did not make changes to 2.5 and 97.5% CI. Using confint function gave totally different numbers. How can I have more digits in my results in svyciprop?